# Escaping character sequences with Jekyll and Liquid

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm currently trying to add the following character sequence to a post using Jekyll:

```
#\^[]|{}~
```

However, whenever I try, I get the error:

```
Liquid Exception: Tag '{%' was not properly terminated with regexp: /\%\}/
```

I've seen multiple posts on this suggesting that I do the following:

```
#\^[]|{{ "{}" }}~
```

This results in a similar error:

```
Liquid Exception: Variable '{{ "{}' was not properly terminated with regexp: /\}\}/
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can temporarily disable Liquid parsing by doing:

```
{% raw %}
  #\^[]|{}~
{% endraw %}
```

Comment: The error I get when doing that is: `Liquid Exception: Tag '{%' was not properly terminated with regexp: /\%\}/ `

Comment: That's literally all I need to repro.

Comment: Yet, it would make sense to show a few lines of code before and after that piece of code. I tried your piece of code, and with raw tags, it worked. So perhaps the error starts elsewhere.

Comment: Even without the raw tags, there are no problems. So the problem does probably start earlier.